# Python Kivy, reference class variable in KV code

Tags: python, oop, kivy

Hello a simple question i can't find an answer to,
Say I have a class:

```
class KivyApp(App):
    someVariable = "blahblah"
```

then say in KV code I want to put text which is the value of 'someVariable'
how can I do that? I tried 'KivyApp.someVariable', 'app.someVariable' 'root.KivyApp.someVariable' ect... and other permutation. So sorry of the basic question but I'm stumped. Appreciate any answers.

Comment: Do you mean 'access' the text which is the value of `someVariable`?

Comment: @quamrana yes that is what i want

Answer (score 0):

This is working

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import StringProperty



kv_str = Builder.load_string("""
Button:
    on_press: print(app.label_text)
""")

class MyApp(App):
    label_text = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.label_text = 'Palim'
        super(MyApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        return kv_str

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

This isn't

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import StringProperty



kv_str = Builder.load_string("""
Button:
    text: app.label_text
    on_press: print(app.label_text)
""")

class MyApp(App):
    label_text = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.label_text = 'Palim'
        super(MyApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        return kv_str

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

I believe kivy has not set the property when it is initializing the text on the Button or in your case label.

But generally, I would stick this text to the Label itself.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class Lbl(Label):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.text = 'Palim'
        super(Lbl, self).__init__(**kwargs)


kv_str = Builder.load_string("""
Lbl:
""")

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return kv_str

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```